# Kafka Connect Messages from s3 connector to aws

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, multipart

I am trying to have Kafka Connect sink multiple messages into the S3 Bucket. So far when I produce multiple rows
{sessionId: 1, userId: 1, timestamp: 2011-10-10}
{sessionId: 2, userId: 2, timestamp: 2011-10-10}

the aws s3 Bucket only shows the first row when I download the json file. It said "unable to expand the file" and when I do click to see the file it only shows the 1st row message produced.

Here is part of my Dockerfile `python3-pip RUN pip3 install awscli`

Deployment.yaml file

```
command:
  -bash
  - -c
  - |
   aws configure set aws_access_key_id "$aws_access_key" &
   aws configure set aws_secret_key "$aws_secret_key" &
   aws configure set default.region us-west-2 &
   /etc/confluent/docker/run &
   bin/connect-distributed.sh config/worker.properties
   echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect ⏳"
    while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) -eq 000 ] ; do 
       echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) " (waiting for 200)"
    sleep 5 
  done
  nc -vz kafka-connect 8083
  echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connector(s)"
  /scripts/create-connectors.sh  # Note: This script is stored externally from container
  bash properties.file
  sleep infinity
```

Properties file:

```
{
```

"name": "meetups-to-s3",
"config": {

```
"_comment": "The S3 sink connector class",                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The total number of Connect tasks to spawn (with implicit upper limit the number of topic-partitions)",                                                                                                                                            
"tasks.max":"1",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "Which topics to export to S3",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
"topics":"meetups",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The S3 bucket that will be used by this connector instance",                                                                                                                                                                                       
"s3.bucket.name":"meetups",                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The AWS region where the S3 bucket is located",                                                                                                                                                                                                    
"s3.region":"us-west-2",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The size in bytes of a single part in a multipart upload. The last part is of s3.part.size bytes or less. This property does not affect the total size of an S3 object uploaded by the S3 connector",                                             
"s3.part.size":"5242880",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The maximum number of Kafka records contained in a single S3 object. Here a high value to allow for time-based partition to take precedence",                                                                                                                                                                              
"flush.size":"100000",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "Kafka Connect converter used to deserialize keys (unused in this example)",                                                                                                                                                                        
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",                                                                                                                                                                                                  
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "Kafka Connect converter used to deserialize values",                                                                                                                                                                                               
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",                                                                                                                                                                                                
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The type of storage for this storage cloud connector",                                                                                                                                                                                             
"storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The storage format of the objects uploaded to S3",                                                                                                                                                                                                 
"format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "Schema compatibility mode between records with schemas (Useful when used with schema-based converters. Unused in this example, listed for completeness)",                                                                                          
"schema.compatibility":"NONE",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The class used to partition records in objects to S3. Here, partitioning based on time is used.",                                                                                                                                                  
"partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The locale used by the time-based partitioner to encode the date string",                                                                                                                                                                          
"locale":"en",

"_comment": "Setting the timezone of the timestamps is also required by the time-based partitioner",                                                                                                                                                            
"timezone":"UTC",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The date-based part of the S3 object key",                                                                                                                                                                                                         
"path.format":"'date'=YYYY-MM-dd/'hour'=HH",                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The duration that aligns with the path format defined above",                                                                                                                                                                                      
"partition.duration.ms":"3600000",                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The interval between timestamps that is sufficient to upload a new object to S3. Here a small interval of 1min for better visualization during the demo",                                                                                          
"rotate.interval.ms":"60000",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"_comment": "The class to use to derive the timestamp for each record. Here Kafka record timestamps are used",                                                                                                                                                  
"timestamp.extractor":"Record"
```

}
}

So my question:Is there a way for Kafka connect to produce multiple messages into 1 file because a topic can have multiple messages, so like multipart? Am I missing anything in the deployment file or properties file? Thank you Any questions please comment

Comment: 1) You don't need awscli 2) Please show the full connector config 3) how many partitions does the topic have?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 1) then how do we start the awscli in docker pipeline 2) i updated the post 3) 3 partitions like what kafka expect

Comment: Not clear why you need awscli. You can give the region in the connector config and the keys by environment variables on the container. And Kafka doesn't "expect" any number of partitions...

Comment: Not clear how frequently data is produced into the topic or its timestamps. If there's only one record timestamp per `partition.duration.ms`, then that'll explain what you're seeing. The default behavior is up to flush.size records per file, per partition

Comment: @OneCricketeer so topic messages are produced by timestamps so if i write multiple messages how do i combine those messages into 1 file do i have to modify the partition.duration.ms, flush.size to higher number

Comment: Do you get multiple files per S3 path? Your values seem fine. If you only get one file in each hour path, then it's working as expected; it's only consuming one record at those hours. You'd have to look at the actual record timestamps manually to see where they lay in terms of your partitioning scheme. But as a test, you could try removing the hour from the path format. You can also try increasing rotate.interval.ms

Comment: @OneCricketeer I see ok I will try that out, but what if data is produced into the topic and not by timestamp and what if s3.compression.type is a gzip file because i currently have it compress to a gzip to zip all messages into 1 but its erroring

Comment: All records have a timestamp as of Kafka 0.10.2... I've never used gzip, only snappy, so not sure there.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Do you know what compression type or configuration way to combine multiple files into 1 file and sink it to s3 bucket

Comment: You cannot get "one file" unless you have only one partition, and a really large flush size. Not by compression, as that is per-file, not a "grouping" operation. You will always end up with one file per kafka partition, as mentioned. The number of records within each file is determined by how frequently you've configured those files to flush/rotate